# Adding multiple styles to single layer with pyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, style, qml, qlr

On QGIS, I would like to programmatically assign multiple .qml styles to a single layer with python.

I can add styles manually from the Properties dialog on the layer by  selecting Styles->Add... but I cannot add them from a .qml

So the question is two-fold:

1. How to add programmatically a second, third, etc style for the layer.
2. If the new styles can be added from  saved .qml's

So far my knowledge is limmited to loading one individual .qml with

```
layer.loadNamedStyle(path_to_qml_1)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with multiple styles in one layer, classifications? QML is a KML type file. Maybe you want to try to parse them together into a single *.qml and load that one?