# Multiple styles using pyqgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, style-manager

I'm trying to automate adding styles to layers, with each layer having multiple styles using **pyqgis**.

Couldn't find any answers except this unanswered question:

[Adding multiple styles to single layer with pyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214218/adding-multiple-styles-to-single-layer-with-pyqgis)

I did manage to add multiple styles using QgsMapLayerStyleManager:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.name()
mlsm = QgsMapLayerStyleManager(layer)
layer.loadNamedStyle('~/Styles/BasinAnalysis/Area/Total.qml')
mlsm.renameStyle("default","Area-Total")
mlsm.addStyleFromLayer("Area-Freshwater")
layer.loadNamedStyle('~/Styles/BasinAnalysis/Area/Freshwater.qml')
mlsm.addStyleFromLayer("Area-Unirrigated")
layer.loadNamedStyle('~/Styles/BasinAnalysis/Area/Unirrigated.qml')
etc...
```

It seems like the multiple styles are associated to layer, and I can also see the changes applies to layer:

```
mlsm.styles()
>>> ['Area-Freshwater', 'Area-Other', 'Area-Saline', 'Area-TWW', 'Area-Total', 'Area-Unirrigated']
```

The problem is that styles don't appear when I right click on Layer -> Styles, it only shows the default layer.

I'm guessing I need to associate the styles from the StyleManager back to the layer, but not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should obtain the style manager from layer instead of creating new one. You can do this with:

```
layer.styleManager()
```

You can read more in QGIS documentation:
https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#ac7ce04c009ac81926b63af4c98bd5c72